# postgresql request to get first occurence of a repeated value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the first occurence of when the position of one of my items is equel to AL, here's an example of what I mean:

```
id  | msr_id | user_id |            date            | pos | 
------+--------+---------+----------------------------+-----+
  210 |     38 |      58 | 2018-06-12 08:53:41.929181 | AL  |
  211 |     38 |      58 | 2018-06-12 08:56:37.223835 | AL  |
  212 |     36 |      56 | 2018-06-12 08:57:35.010093 | AR  |
  213 |     38 |      58 | 2018-06-12 09:00:54.841769 | AL  |
  214 |     36 |      56 | 2018-06-12 09:02:13.51732  | RR  |
```

this is my table and, if you look at the example you can see that when msr_id is equal to 38, I have multiple passages in the AL position, I want to be able to get the first one of those passages, in this example the one where the actual id is equal to 210, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (msr_id) t.*
from t
where pos = 'AL'
order by msr_id, date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,msr_id from your_table where pos='AL' 
order by date asc
limit 1
```

Comment: This solution also worked, thank you for your help!

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it only get the very first one, I would've wanted to have all the first occurences depending on the msr_id not just the first one, thank you for your help though it's greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: you are right. I guess answer below is more suitable for general situation

Comment: for this specific case, the answer below was a more suited solution but I still do realy appreciate your help and I was able to complete other tasks with the general layout of the sql request you provided me with. So thanks!